# How to use Realm with feature-module structure?

Tags: android, realm, android-instant-apps

I want to rewrite my app to instant-app. But I get some problems with importing Realm to feature module. If I write

`apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'
apply plugin:'realm-android'`

in the feature module Gradle can't build project and the error is:

`Error:(2, 0) The android or android-library plugin must be applied to the project`

But if I put this plugin to application module, classes from base module can't use Realm.

`apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin:'realm-android'`

The error will be next: 
`Error:(23, 16) error: package io.realm does not exist`

How to use realm in a feature module?

Comment: I have a better question, how will you stay under the 4 MB APK limit with Realm @ChristianMelchior

Comment: I will separate app for few modules. Some for instant app and some for installed app. The problem is that I can't use `apply plugin:` in feature module.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce how big is Realm in terms of MB?

Comment: ~1MB pr. CPU architecture supported. The standard package is around 6 MB. Using APK Split can reduce that massively though.

Comment: I'm not sure if it works, but you can try to create separate library module, add realm plugin to it, and import this module in your base feature `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 2):

Realm explicitly checks for the existence of `com.android.application` or `com.android.library` plugins. Since it is not aware of `com.android.feature` plugin, you receive an exception.

https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/7dbacb438f8f1130155eacf06347fce703c8f1a8/gradle-plugin/src/main/groovy/io/realm/gradle/Realm.groovy#L34

```
void apply(Project project) {
    // Make sure the project is either an Android application or library
    def isAndroidApp = project.plugins.withType(AppPlugin)
    def isAndroidLib = project.plugins.withType(LibraryPlugin)
    if (!isAndroidApp && !isAndroidLib) {
        throw new GradleException("'com.android.application' or 'com.android.library' plugin required.")
    }
```

Comment: Note for app bundles; use `apply plugin: "realm-android"` in your base module. Feature modules can still use Realm code, inheriting the Realm dependency from the base module. I just needed to remove `apply plugin: "realm-android"` from the feature module.